GoogleAppsScriptにてcreateEventでguestsに招待メールが届かない
スプレッドシートからカレンダーに予定を作成して参加者に出欠確認のメールを送信したいため、下記のように設定していますが、guestsに設定しているメールアドレスに招待メールが届きません。
相手側のGoogleカレンダーの設定は予定の作成時にメールが届く設定にはなっています。
実行でエラーは発生せず、カレンダーに予定は自分と相手の両方に正常に作成されているため、どこが問題かが分かりません。
他にどこを確認すべきか教えていただきたく思います。
calendar.createEvent(
          title,
          startDate,
          endDate,
          
          { description : description ,
            guests : guests ,
            sendInvites : true
          }

